# Processing 3.0 PVector.get()

Tags: java, processing

Apparently in Processing 3.0+ they have deprecated PVector.get(). Out of curiosity, if PVector.get() is deprecated, how *should* we be making a deep copy of PVectors from now on?

Since this version is still in Beta, they haven't quite updated all the documentation (unless I'm just missing something).

Thanks!

Comment: No, but when you use the function within their IDE it highlights it yellow and gives a warning about it.

Here's a link to a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/1W9Lail.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. It seems they just want you to use the .copy() method.

That makes sense. Hope they update their documentation soon!

Comment: Replacing `PVector.get()` with `PVector.copy()`. New method worked. Replaced method `get()` with method `copy()` in the following string. `PVector friction = movers[i].velocity.copy();` This worked.